# Add some OpenCV processing to a gstreamer video stream

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I'm trying to have OpenCV process a frame in the middle of a gstreamer pipe.

I have one gstreamer pipe generating the stream, sending it to appsink for OpenCV code to receive:

```
v4l2src ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! appsink name=sink
```

And another pipe getting it from appsrc (to which OpenCV sends data) and outputting it on the screen:

```
appsrc name=src ! jpegdec ! xvimagesink
```

I open every frame with a pull-buffer request on sink and process it with OpenCV, then use push-buffer on src. I am doing all that in Python.

For some reason, that does not seem to work (segmentation fault).

But I'm not really trying to fix it; it's terribly inefficient anyway. I am just wondering whether there any better way to have OpenCV process the frame before it reaches an output sink?

Comment: Since you want more than what gst-opencv can offer, if you don't mind writing your logic in C (or C++), perhaps you should try writing it as a plugin to gst? You can take one of the gst-opencv plugins' source as a starting point

Comment: Another thing - your example seems to just grabbing from v4l2, and I think opencv's HighGui API supports that already (or at least v4l without the '2'). that would be the easiest solution if you don't really need gstreamer.

Comment: 1. Good suggestion, I might do that.

2. You're right, I could use HighGUI in this case, but v4l2src was used merely as an example. In the actual application I intend to get the video stream from a tcp source, so I can't really implement the whole thing in OpenCV.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try [gst-opencv](https://github.com/Elleo/gst-opencv)? It supplies several opencv primitives as gstreamer plugins.

**EDIT**: Seems like it's merged into [gst-plugins-bad](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-plugins-bad.html), and the link above is outdated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I considered gst-opencv but decided against it because I want the freedom to process the video frames in any way I want (for example, apply domain-specific machine learning algorithms), and the options offered by gst-opencv are very generic.

Answer (score 1):

I know some years have passed since your original question, but just for the record, OpenCv can open Gstreamer pipelines directly. See the (self-)answer in [Using custom camera in OpenCV (via GStreamer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570572/using-custom-camera-in-opencv-via-gstreamer) for an example.

And, by the way, [OpenCv 3.0](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki) (master branch) actually integrates gstreamer 1.0 support.