# Python with Gstreamer pipeline

Tags: python, c++, opencv, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I'm working on an Udoo trying to get the camera to take a picture that I can manipulate inside Python.

So far, the camera works with

`gst-launch-1.0 imxv4l2videosrc ! imxipuvideosink`

I can also take a single picture with

`gst-launch-1.0 imxv4l2videosrc num-buffers=1 ! video/x-raw ! jpegenc ! filesink location=output.jpg`

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570572/using-custom-camera-in-opencv-via-gstreamer) it seems like you can read straight from a gstreamer stream in Python with OpenCV.

Here is my python code:

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("imxv4l2videosrc ! video/x-raw ! appsink")
ret, image = cam.read()
```

However, ret is `False`, and image is nothing.

Some places say this only works with OpenCV 3.0+, and others say 2.4.x, but I can't seem to find an actual answer to what version it works on.

If I need to update to OpenCV 3.0, which part to I update?  I downloaded OpenCV via the apt repositories under the package python-opencv.  So do I need to update Python?  Can I just build OpenCV from source, and Python will automatically be using the newest version?  I'm so confused.

Comment: Probably couldn't have picked a worse time ever to post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu/Debian version is old 2.4.x, to get the last one you need to compile it from source.

Here two tutorials on how to do that:

1. https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_fedora/py_setup_in_fedora.html#installing-opencv-from-source
2. http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/

The first is for `Python 2.7` on `Fedora`, the second for `Python 3.4` on `Ubuntu`.

Comment: I cross referenced both your links and got OpenCV with Python 2.7 running on an Udoo Dual.  In case anyone lands here from a search, I posted on the Udoo forums: http://www.udoo.org/forum/threads/using-udoo-camera-with-opencvs-videocapture-class-2-0.6130/#post-23716