# Access Camera using OpenCV (Via GStreamer)

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-streaming, gstreamer

I'm trying to develop an application which should analyse a video stream from a MIPI camera(5MP). So I'm using gstreamer to get the video feed access it using OpenCV. I tried the following pipeline and it's working:

```
imxv4l2videosrc device="/dev/video0" ! autovideosink
```

But when I try to use it with OpenCV, it gives some errors.

```
VideoCapture cap("imxv4l2videosrc device=\"/dev/video0\" ! autovideosink");

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: cannot find appsink in manual pipeline
) in cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer, file /root/OpenCV/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 759
VIDEOIO(cvCreateCapture_GStreamer (CV_CAP_GSTREAMER_FILE, filename)): raised OpenCV exception:

/root/OpenCV/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:759: error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot find appsink in manual pipeline
 in function cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer
```

Then I tried to use the following pipeline, and it's not working as well:

```
VideoCapture cap("imxv4l2videosrc device=\"/dev/video0\" ! appsink");

ERROR: unrecognized std! 0 (PAL=ff, NTSC=b000
ERROR: v4l2 capture: unsupported ioctrl!
GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module imxv4l2videosrc0 reported: Internal data flow error.
ERROR: v4l2 capture: unsupported ioctrl!
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
) in cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer, file /root/OpenCV/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 832
VIDEOIO(cvCreateCapture_GStreamer (CV_CAP_GSTREAMER_FILE, filename)): raised OpenCV exception:

/root/OpenCV/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:832: error: (-2) GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
 in function cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer
```

GStreamer version: 1.0
OpenCV version: 3.2

What is the piece i'm missing here?
Or is my approach is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate and solution at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570572/using-custom-camera-in-opencv-via-gstreamer

Comment: @GroovyDotCom, I've already tried the post you've mentioned here. But mfw_v4lsrc is not working. it says: WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "mfw_v4lsrc".

Comment: Could you try it with a `videoconvert` element? : `VideoCapture cap("imxv4l2videosrc device=\"/dev/video0\" ! videoconvert ! appsink");`

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler, it worked :). But still I'm getting some errors:
ERROR: unrecognized std! 0 (PAL=ff, NTSC=b000
ERROR: v4l2 capture: unsupported ioctrl!

Any idea about this?

Comment: It seems to me like a problem with camera settings. You may need to set some flags with your `imxv4l2videosrc` elements. I've never used that one but you may see the settings related to this element using the  `gst-inspect-1.0 imxv4l2videosrc` command.

Comment: AlperKucukkomurler, Thanks for the information. Also I'm having a doubt whether I'm getting the image in 5MP. Because I took a frame with OpenCV and the size was 640x480 px. How should I change that?

Comment: try v4l2-ctl --list-ctrls

Comment: When you find the answer, suggest you add a comment  to the original question with your gstreamer 1.0 solution.

Comment: Generally in gstreamer, you configure the format you want out of an element with a format descriptor in the pipeline: Something like gst-launch v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240,framerate=25/1 ! ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question(with @Alper Kucukkomurler's help)

You can access the MIPI camera through OpenCV (with GStreamer) with

```
VideoCapture cap("imxv4l2videosrc device=\"/dev/video0\" ! videoconvert ! appsink");
```

Also If you want to change the resolution of the input, `imx-capture-mode` parameter can be used, which is of `imxv4l2videosrc` element.
For example,

```
imxv4l2videosrc imx-capture-mode=5 ! <other elements>
```